# DRF delete request to Heroku

Tags: heroku, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to send a DELETE http request to my DRF API at Heroku, and I'm getting an empty response, although it's working perfectly at localhost.

Any known issues with Heroku here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just figured it. It seems gunicorn in Heroku is kinda configured not to accept DELETE requests out of a secure protocol.

I've sent the request via HTTPS and it worked perfectly.